# Crashing with Memory Mismanagement with Parse SDK

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to add a new user to Parse but it is throwing an error:

```
[__NSCFData PF_base64EncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I did find the objective-c temporary fix.. "is a category on NSData that provides the missing selectors. Here it is a header, NSData+PFData.h:" But how do I implement this solution in swift? ([Parse v1.7.4 and Facebook SDK NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData PF_dataFromBase64String:]: unrecognized selector sent to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397475/parse-v1-7-4-and-facebook-sdk-nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-nsdata-pf))

I read that I could be mismanaging my memory where a "method to be sent to another object that is now occupying the memory that the view controller was previously occupying..." But I tried checking for this and my classes on my view controllers are ok, is there another instance of this?

```
 var i = 13

    func addPerson(urlString:String){

        var newUser = PFUser()

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: .mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in


            newUser["image"] = data

            newUser["gender"] = "female"

            var lat = Double(37 + i)

            var lon = Double(-122 + i)

            i = i + 10

            var location = PFGeoPoint(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)

            newUser["location"] = location

            newUser.username = "\(i)"

            newUser.password = "password"

            //newUser.signUp()
            newUser.signUpInBackground()

        }

    }

    addPerson("http://irishamerica.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/George-Clooney.jpg")
```

I just want George Clooney to be a user in my app. Is that to much to ask.

Comment: Why do you think this is a memory management error? The post you link to has the solution. Just add the ObjC category files. Parse is in ObjC. There's no reason to try to rework that piece in Swift, especially since it's a temporary workaround for a Parse bug.

Comment: You're right that did fix the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" however it did result in a "Received memory warning." So that's why I couldn't tell if it as a memory management error. Have you heard of this new error? Some say it's just a bug in Xcode but seams hard to believe.

Comment: A memory warning is completely different. It means you're using too much memory and the system is warning you that you'll be killed if you don't reduce your usage. It usually means you're leaking. For an excellent introduction to tracking down memory leaks, see http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ (and of course first make sure you have no warnings from the compiler or the static analyzer).